# HTML - Make one button having two functions

Tags: html, function, button, label

I have two HTML elements. One is a button that opens my sidebar which works in the mobile version.

```
<a href="#header" class="button scrolly">Contact Me</a>.
```

The second element is a label when clicked, it selects the name field from the contact form.

```
<label for="name">Name Select<label>
```

Does anyone know how to join this two functions together so when header opens, and then the name field is selected? The two functions need to work as a button.

Comment: Paste your javascript code here. So people can see what you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onclick` in Javascript...

```
<button onclick="SomeJSAction()">Click Me</button>

<script>

function SomeJSAction() {
//open menu and select form.

}

</script>
```